# Highcharts legend items on one line and overlapping

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts.js to render a bunch of charts to some divs that are jqueryUI draggables. In Chrome, this works perfectly fine. However, in Internet Explorer (tested in 11, but maybe in other versions too), there are some scaling issues. The script that renders the charts runs different settings based on browser, so I can mess with the IE part by itself without messing up the Chrome part. This is how it *should* look (and how it does in Chrome):

[image]

Everything is nicely spaced, and I didn't have to set any spacing options. This is how it looks in IE11. I added some margins to the plot itself, because it was originally rendering outside of the div entirely:

[image]

The scaling issues and misplacement of the y-axis labels I can deal with, that's easy to change. My issue is the legend. In Chrome, I set no specific options for the legend and I was fine. Apparently that doesn't work for IE. I can't find any documentation or help on why this is happening. All of the items are present, and you can still click on them for normal behavior. They are all just stuck on one line like that.

Has anyone encountered this issue before/have any ideas to fix it? I tried a whole bunch of options for the legend in the chart settings, but other than being able to move it around (while still stuck on one line) I can't affect it.

code sample:
HTML

```
<div id="dropwrap">
<div id="dock">
    <div id="dockhead">Available Cards</div>
    <!--div class="draggable" id="drag1">10 Year History</div-->
    <div class="draggable" id="drag2" style="top:180px;">Premium<br>Pie Chart</div>
    <div class="draggable" id="drag3" style="top:230px;">Loss<br>Pie Chart</div>
    <div class="draggable" id="drag4" style="top:280px;">Premium<br>History Chart</div>
    <div class="draggable" id="drag5" style="top:330px;">Loss<br>History Chart</div>
    <div class="draggable" id="drag6" style="top:380px;">Loss Ratio<br>History Chart</div>
</div>
<div id="expand">
    <div id="hlpmsg" style="text-weight: bold; font-size: 150%; position: absolute; top: 350px; left: 500px;">Drag cards here to expand them!</div>
</div>

</div>
```

JS

```
function areachartgen(chtype, item) {
console.log($(item));
$('#drag4').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'area',
        backgroundColor: '#57CF57',
        borderColor: '#000',
        borderRadius: '10px',
        marginBottom: 150,
        marginLeft: 70,
        marginTop: 40
    },
    legend: {
        floating: true,
        itemStyle: {
            'lineHeight': '20px'
        },
        maxHeight: 150,
        labelFormatter: function () {
            return this.name;
        },
        layout: 'vertical'
    },
    title: {
        text: '10 Year ' + chtype + ' History'
    },
    /*subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: <a href="http://thebulletin.metapress.com/content/c4120650912x74k7/fulltext.pdf">' +
                    'thebulletin.metapress.com</a>'
            },*/
    xAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value; // clean, unformatted number for year
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: chtype
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                if (chtype === "Loss Ratio") {
                    return this.value + '%';
                } else {
                    return '$' + this.value / 1000 + 'k';
                }
            },
            labels: {
                overflow: "justify"
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}',
        valueDecimals: 2
    },
    plotOptions: {
        area: {
            pointStart: 1940,
            marker: {
                enabled: false,
                symbol: 'circle',
                radius: 2,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            },
            stacking: "normal"
        }
    },
    colors: [
        '#6FF299', '#5A90D6', '#E39220', '#D17BC6', '#8085e9',
        '#f15c80', '#e4d354', '#8085e8', '#8d4653', '#91e8e1'],
    series: [{
        name: 'Casualty',
        data: [
            [2004, 360902.0],
            [2005, 371489.0],
            [2006, 398748.0],
            [2007, 416682.0],
            [2008, 413205.0],
            [2009, 374988.0],
            [2010, 400701.0],
            [2011, 483902.0],
            [2012, 447391.0],
            [2013, 456503.0]
        ]
    }, {
        name: 'Engineering',
        data: [
            [2004, 0.0],
            [2005, 0.0],
            [2006, 0.0],
            [2007, 0.0],
            [2008, 0.0],
            [2009, 0.0],
            [2010, 0.0],
            [2011, 0.0],
            [2012, 0.0],
            [2013, 0.0]
        ]
    }, {
        name: 'Ocean Marine',
        data: [
            [2004, 0.0],
            [2005, 180000.0],
            [2006, 234395.0],
            [2007, 248322.0],
            [2008, 262216.0],
            [2009, 248754.0],
            [2010, 274888.0],
            [2011, 289781.0],
            [2012, 340459.0],
            [2013, 405247.0]
        ]
    }, {
        name: 'Property',
        data: [
            [2004, 285354.0],
            [2005, 365038.0],
            [2006, 395420.0],
            [2007, 554621.0],
            [2008, 685197.0],
            [2009, 630535.0],
            [2010, 613608.0],
            [2011, 643399.0],
            [2012, 704345.32],
            [2013, 822684.93]
        ]
    }]
});
$(item).resize();
```

}

Here is a link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dLL8cw7s/5/

Oddly, everything works perfectly fine in the fiddle, even in IE. But not when running on my website.

Comment: You need to include code or better yet a jsFiddle that demonstartes your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I was including the platform.js from Polymer, which I had been using for a scaffold previously. That added some polyfill elements and screwed everything up. I'm not using Polymer anymore, so once I got rid of that one line that included the platform, everything worked perfectly.